# Sql query: How change of table will leads to different result?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

The database is:

Highschooler ( ID, name, grade ) English: There is a high school student with unique ID and a given first name in a certain grade.

Friend ( ID1, ID2 ) English: The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2. Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is (456, 123).

Likes ( ID1, ID2 ) English: The student with ID1 likes the student with ID2. Liking someone is not necessarily mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Likes table, there is no guarantee that (456, 123) is also present.

The task is to: Find names and grades of students who only have friends in the same grade. Return the result sorted by grade, then by name within each grade.

These two commands seem should generate same result, but the fact is not.

The correct command is:

```
select distinct name, grade
from Highschooler s1
where not exists (select * from Highschooler s2, Friend
                  where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID
                  and s1.ID = Friend.ID1 
                  and s2.grade <> s1.grade)
 order by grade, name
```

But I also think the following command which only change the position of Friend also make sense:

```
select distinct name, grade
from Highschooler s1, Friend
where not exists (select * from Highschooler s2
                   where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID
                  and s1.ID = Friend.ID1 
                  and s2.grade <> s1.grade)
 order by grade, name
```

But the latter one only return all the value in table Highschooler.

I really thinks that change the position of Friend won't make a difference in the result but it seems that the result is different.

This phenomenon is confusing and I really appreciate it if some experts can provide some help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid using implicit comma-separated joins (e.g. `from Highschooler s2, Friend`) and use explicit joins (`from Highschooler s2 inner join Friend on ...`) instead. They are more readable and less prone to errors.

Your first query looks up highschoolers where no friend highschooler with another grade exists. The DISTINCT seems superfluous. Well, you would remove persons who happen to have the same name and grade as another.

Your second query cross joins highschoolers and friends table, i.e. get all combinations whether related or not. For each such combination it makes sure that no highschooler exists where the combined friend happens to be the highschoolers friend and the friend has another grade. So you keep all combinations of highschooler and friend who don't belong together. In short: This query makes no sense.

Actually it rarely makes sense to cross joins tables, and you didn't want to cross join them. You did that by mistake, because you used the old comma-separated join syntax that was replaced by explicit joins more than twenty years ago. If you had told the DBMS you want to join the tables so to get related records (i.e. `from Highschooler s2 inner join Friend`), it would have told you that you are missing the ON clause to specify how the records are related.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your kind comment! I just begin to learn sql from stanford online course. From your comment, I think we can simply get the right answer be adding an extra condition of the second query: and s1.ID = Friend.ID1 although this condition exist in the (). And essentially that condition makes the second query into the first one.

Comment: Well, you *could* tweak the second query somehow, but why? The first query does exactly what is needed in a straight-forward manner. Only, I would replace the join syntax as mentioned for the sake of readability.

Comment: I have modified the query to this form:                                               select distinct name, grade
from (Highschooler s1 inner join Friend on (s1.ID = Friend.ID1)) A
where not exists (select * from Highschooler s2
                  where A.ID2 = s2.ID
                  and s2.grade <> A.grade)
 order by grade, name

Comment: But this one still return different result from the correct query. Where make these two queries different?

Comment: This is because now you join highschooler and friend and only keep those pairs for which the friend has the same grade. This is not what you want. The correct query is correct, because it does exactly what is desired: select highschoolers (i.e. select ... from highschoolers, no join) for which not exist friends with another grade (NOT EXISTS clause with the friend table and a join with the friend highschooler to see his/her grade).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are excluding some of the records from the exists statement with your where clause that are not excluded when you put the friend table outside the exists.

If you remove the where clause the missing records would appear.

~CiscoKid

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only change is the position of Friend. The first one is correct but I don't see how the second one is not

Comment: The second one is not correct because of the fact you include friend in your subselect:

    select distinct name, grade
    from Highschooler s1, Friend
    where not exists (select * from Highschooler s2
                       where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID
                      and s1.ID = Friend.ID1 
                      and s2.grade <> s1.grade)
     order by grade, name 

There are three filters you put on the subselect / exists statement. Those filters are affecting the records that are being returned which is causing the discrepancy.

Comment: Why the second one is not correct? The goal is to"Find names and grades of students who only have friends in the same grade. Return the result sorted by grade, then by name within each grade.".  The second one is the right answer. This is the standard answer in stanford online course

Answer (score 0):

Your first query also returns people with no friends, you should add...

```
and exists (select * from Highschooler s2, Friend
            where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID
             and s1.ID = Friend.ID1 
             and s2.grade = s1.grade)
```

...to your `where` clause.

I've tested your second query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08ea7/17) and it's returning every record. There is no relation between your Highschooler s1 and your Friend tables outside your subquery. If you put your Friends table into the subquery like this:

```
select id, name, grade
from Highschooler s1
where not exists (select id from Highschooler s2, Friend
                  where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID
                   and s1.ID = Friend.ID1 
                   and s2.grade <> s1.grade)
```

...and add...

```
and exists (select id from Highschooler s2, Friend
               where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID
              and s1.ID = Friend.ID1 
              and s2.grade = s1.grade)
```

...it will return the desired records. Tested [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08ea7/29).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and test! Yes it also returns people with no friends but the second query seems make more serious mistake since it will return all the value in the table instead of "Find names and grades of students who only have friends in the same grade. "

Comment: The goal is to  "Find names and grades of students who only have friends in the same grade. " and I am wondering why the second query won't achieve this goal

Comment: Updated answer: I've tried answering _why the second query won't achieve that goal_

Comment: Thank you for your update. What does "There is no relation between your Highschooler s1 and your Friend tables outside your subquery." means?  In the second subquery we have condition "where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID" Right? That actually put some constraint on the result.

Comment: _In the second subquery we have condition "where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID" Right?_ RIGHT. I mean your subquery uses the table `Friend` for the `where` clause, but there is no `Friend` table in its `from` clause but in main query where it's not related to your `Highschooler s1` table (main query, not subquery). That's why I think it returns every record

Comment: select distinct name, grade
from Highschooler s1, Friend f1
where not exists (select * from Highschooler s2
                   where f1.ID2 = s2.ID
                  and s1.ID = f1.ID1 
                  and s2.grade <> s1.grade)
 order by grade, name

Comment: How about this? I tried this one and it DOESN'T WORK neither. I think in this one Highschooler s1, f1, s2 are connected?

Comment: It's the same difference again, your first query works and the 2nd one doesn't, because of the `Friend` table location (main query vs subquery)